# reading a line of input c

Tags: c99, getline

I'm trying to write a C99 program (without GNU extensions if at all possible) need to take input from the user of arbitrary length. Here is what I have so far and it keeps SEGFAULT-ing on line 26.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int get_line(char* buffer, FILE* fp) {
    int bufread = 0;
    int bufsize = LINE_MAX;
    if(buffer == NULL) {
        buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*bufsize);
        strcpy(buffer, "");
    }

    while(true) {
        if(bufread == bufsize) {
            bufsize += LINE_MAX;
            buffer = (char*)realloc(buffer, sizeof(char)*bufsize);
        }

        char character = fgetc(fp);

        if(character == '\n') {
            break;
        } else {
            strcat(buffer, character);
            bufread += 1;
        }
    }

    return bufread;
}

int main() {
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    char* string = NULL;
    int chars_read = get_line(string, stdin);
    printf("The number of chars read is %d\n", chars_read);
    printf("The string you entered was %s\n", string);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 2nd parameter to [`strcat()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) should be `const char *`.

Comment: Since you are reading 1 char at a time, there's no need for `strcat()`. Just keep a running index and put the char in there: `buffer[index++] = character;`. Don't forget to add `buffer[index] = '\0';` before the `return`.

Comment: Also, passing `string` to `get_line` will not result in `string` being modified, so the `printf` on line 39 will not do what you want.  It would be easier to have `get_line` return a pointer to the read-in string and then just use `strlen` to discover how many chars are in the string.  An alternative is to pass a _pointer to_ `string` as the argument to `get_line`, but that's slightly harder to deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `get_line`

> ```
>    buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*bufsize);
>    strcpy(buffer, "");
> ```

- to do a *strcpy* to just set the first character to 0 is a complicated way, just do `*buffer = 0;`.
- `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition
- you do not need to do the cast

Note also that if *buffer* is not given NULL in argument the behavior is dangerous and can be undefined because the code supposes the given buffer has at least `LINE_MAX` character.

In

> ```
>   char character = fgetc(fp);
> ```

you cannot detect the EOF, need to be an *int*

In

> ```
>    if(character == '\n') {
>        break;
> ```

You missed to detect the EOF

You missed to add the null character at the end of *buffer* here of after the *while*

In

> ```
> strcat(buffer, character);
> ```

this is invalid because the second argument of *strcat* must be a `char*`, *strcat* concatenate two strings, not a string with a character

Supposing there is a *strcat* to append a character that way to do will each time search for the end of the string to append the character, just use *bufread* gicing the index

Because the profile of the function is

> ```
> int get_line(char* buffer, FILE* fp) {
> ```

when you go out of `get_line` you lost the current value of *buffer*, creating a memory leak, and in *main* `printf("The string you entered was %s\n", string);` printf the null pointer. To avoid that you can give the string as an output parameter, allowing you to still return the new length :

---

A proposal :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

size_t get_line(char ** buffer, FILE* fp) {
  size_t bufsize = LINE_MAX;
  size_t bufread = 0;

  *buffer = malloc(bufsize);

  if (*buffer == NULL)
    return 0;

  while (true) {
    if (bufread == bufsize) {
      bufsize += LINE_MAX;
      *buffer = realloc(*buffer, bufsize);
    }

    int character = fgetc(fp);

    if ((character == '\n') || (character == EOF)) {
      (*buffer)[bufread] = 0;
      /* note you can do : *buffer = realloc(*buffer, bufread + 1); to only use the needed memory */
      return bufread;
    }

    (*buffer)[bufread++] = character;
  }
}

int main() {
  printf("Enter a string: ");

  char * string = NULL;
  size_t chars_read = get_line(&string, stdin);

  if (string != NULL) {
    printf("The number of chars read is %zu\n", chars_read);
    printf("The string you entered was '%s'\n", string);
    free(string);
  }
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra p.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter a string: is it working ?
The number of chars read is 15
The string you entered was 'is it working ?'
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter a string: 
The number of chars read is 0
The string you entered was ''
```

And under *valgrind* :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==20382== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==20382== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==20382== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==20382== Command: ./a.out
==20382== 
Enter a string: what about memory leak ?
The number of chars read is 24
The string you entered was 'what about memory leak ?'
==20382== 
==20382== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20382==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20382==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 4,096 bytes allocated
==20382== 
==20382== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==20382== 
==20382== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==20382== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```